# The proof for the Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Im looking at the proof of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem#Proof

I don't see why this line is true.
[image]

This looks like the triangle inequality but it's an equality?

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the terms on the right side. The terms $-\frac 1 {|B|} \int_B g(y)dy$ and $+\frac 1 {|B|} \int_B g(y)dy$ cancel each other and so do the terms $-g(x)$ and $+g(x)$.